# Search view with multiple pages and order by relevancy

Tags: html, django, search

I am writing a very simple search view:

```
class SearchView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/search.html'
    context_object_name = 'results'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Extract query from parameters and return search results.
        """
        query = self.request.GET.get('query')
        if query:
            query = query.strip()
            return Question.objects.filter(question_text__icontains=query)
        else:
            return Question.objects.none()

<!DOCTYPE html>
{% if results %}
<ul>
    {% for result in results %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:vote' result.id %}">{{ result }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No matches found.</p>
{% endif %}
<p><a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">Back to overview?</a></p>
```

The results should be ordered by the total votes on choices:

`Question.objects.filter(question_text__icontains=query).order_by('choice__votes')`

- This query does not seem to work and returns questions multiple times.
- How could the results be split on multiple pages?

Comment: Is same `question object` repeating multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe it's useful if you attach your **Question**  Django model, because I don't understand your error.

Regarding pagination, here is some useful Django classes that I use in my application:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/pagination/

It is very simple to use.

Comment: @R3turnz, i can't comment on your answer due to low reputation :(

Did you resolve all problems? Glad to have helped you with pagination :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! The pagination was exactly what I was looking for.

I wanted to make a query on a reverse foreign key relation ship:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField('text', max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('publication date', default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField('text', max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField('votes', default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

The solution was to use annotations:

```
results.annotate(total_votes=Sum('choice__votes')).order_by('-total_votes')
```